# Derivative of a continuous function.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $g:R\to R$ be a continuous function with $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y), \forall x,y\in R.$ Find $\frac{dg}{dx},$ if it exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* Prove that $g(x) = rx, \forall x \in \mathbb{R} $ where $g(1) := r \in \mathbb{R}.$

*EDIT1:* Let $g(1) = r.$ Then $g(n) = g(1 + 1 + \cdots + 1)= g(1) + g(1) + \cdots + g(1) = ng(1) = nr, \forall n \in \mathbb N.$ Also $g(0) = 2g(0) \Rightarrow g(0) = 0 \Rightarrow g(0) = g(n - n) = g(n) + g(-n) \Rightarrow g(-n) = - g(n), \forall n \in \mathbb N.$ Thus $g(n) = nr, \forall n \in \mathbb Z.$ Also for any $n \in \mathbb Z, n\neq 0,  r = g(1) = g(n. \frac{1}{n}) = n g(\frac{1}{n}),$ showing that $g(\frac{1}{n}) =  \frac{r}{n}.$ From this we can conclude that $g(\frac{m}{n}) = r \cdot \frac{m}{n}, \forall m, n \in \mathbb Z, n \neq 0.$ Now use continuity to conclude that $g(x) = rx, \forall x \in \mathbb R.$

*EDIT2:* Let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function such that $f(x) = 0, \forall x \in \mathbb Q.$ Take $\alpha \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q.$ Choose a sequence $(x_n)$ of rationals such that $x_n \to \alpha.$ Then by continuity, $f(x_n) \to f(\alpha).$ But $f(x_n) = 0, \forall n \in \mathbb N.$ So $f(\alpha) = 0.$ This is true for every $\alpha \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q.$ Hence $f(x) = 0, \forall x \in  \mathbb R.$ (In the above context, take $f := g(x) -  rx.$)

Comment: @Aysha A. I have edited my answer for a complete (!) solution. Feel free to ask if you have any doubt.

Comment: Pls. Why is it that $g(n) = nr, g(-n) = - g(n), \forall n \in \mathbb N?$

Comment: Thanks. But how do i use continuity to show that $g(x) = rx, \forall x \in \mathbb R?$ And also $g(0) = 2g(0)\to g(0)=0$ is not clear to me.

Comment: @AyshaA.: I added a clarification. And for $g(0) =0,$ first note that $g(0) = g(0) + g(0) = 2g(0).$ Now subtract $g(0)$ from both sides.

Comment: Means that:Let $f(x):=g(x)−rx,\forall x\in \mathbb Q.$ Taking $\alpha\in \mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$ and by choosing a sequence $(x_n)$ of rationals such that $x_n\to\alpha,$ then, by continuity, we get $f(x_n)\to f(\alpha).$ But $f(x_n)=g(x_n)−rx,\forall n\in \mathbb N.$ So  $f(\alpha)=g(x)−rx=0,$ which is true for every $\alpha\in \mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q.$ Hence $g(x)=rx,\forall x\in \mathbb R.$ Right?

Comment: $f(x) = g(x) - rx, \forall x \in \mathbb R.$ Take $\alpha \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ and chose a rational sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n \to \alpha.$ Then $f(x_n) \to f(\alpha)$ and $f(\alpha) = g(\alpha) - r \alpha.$ But $f(x_n) = 0 ,\forall n \in \mathbb N \Rightarrow f(\alpha) = 0.$

Comment: Thank you very much! But does $g'(x)=g'(0)$ has any meaning; as suggested in Simon and Winter's answers below?

Comment: I don't know whether $g'(x) = g'(0), \forall x \in \mathbb R$ has any major consequences or not. It means that the derivative is constant. But beyond that I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

First what does $g(0)$ equal?

Second,

$$\frac{g(x+h) - g(x)}{h} = \frac{g(x) + g(h) - g(x)}{h} = \frac{g(h)}{h}$$

So what can you conclude about the derivative of $g$ in general?

Comment: Sorry. I'm not clear, could you shade more light?

Answer (score 1):

First we have $g(0) = 2g(0)\to g(0)=0$. Then it follows that

$$g'(x) = \lim_{y\to 0}\frac{g(x+y)-g(x)}{y} = \lim_{y\to 0}\frac{g(y)}{y} = \lim_{y\to 0}\frac{g(y)-g(0)}{y} = g'(0)$$

As noted below in the comments, this only shows that if $g'(x)$ exist for one $x$ then it exist for all $x$ and is indeed a constant.

Comment: You have to be a bit careful, you also have to show that the limit exists.

Comment: @N.U. Yes, that is correct. I'm assuming here that $g'(0)$ exists, and that needs to be proven.

Comment: I see. Is there an easy way to do that? I would do as Krish did, to show that it's linear, but then it's obvious what the derivative is.

Comment: @N.U. Yes, establishing $\frac{g(m/n)}{m/n} = g(1)$ is enough (and needed I think), but as you say then the problem is almost solved as it follows that $g(x) = xg(1)$. The strongest we can say without doing that is that if $g'(x)$ exist for one $x$ then it exist for all $x$ and is indeed a constant. I think, in hignsight, that Krish's answer is the way to go.

Comment: Okay, so your approach isn't that different from his, but it's always nice to have several ways to do see it.

Comment: @Winther The question ask to find $\frac{dg}{dx}$ So why $g'(x) = \lim_{y\to 0}\frac{g(x+y)-g(x)}{y}?$ Or do you mean $g'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}?$ That is, taking the limit as $h\to 0$ along the $x,$ where $h\in \mathbb R$

Comment: @AyshaA. The two expression you wrote up for $g'(x)$ are identical. It doesn't matter if we call the limit variable $h$ or $y$.